# Raphael 2.1.0 not able to draw lines in firefox browser 38.0.1

Tags: firefox, raphael, firefox-developer-tools, html5-apps

We are using Raphael library to draw our business integration diagram. 
Recently we noticed Raphael is not able to draw lines if the application is opened in Firefox browser ( tested both version 37.0 and 38.0 ).
We tried the following raphael script to draw some sample line using 
https://jsfiddle.net/ on firefox browser

```
var paper = Raphael(10, 10, 630, 480);

var c = paper.path("M10 10L90 90L100 200 L10 10");

c.attr({
    fill:"#900",
    stroke:"black"
});
```

In jsfiddle load Raphael 2.1.0 before trying above snippet 
In Chrome it is able to draw shape and fill color. But in Firefox(version 38) it is not working we see a blank screen.

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/q3kcwyLe/1/

Comment: Hi Robert , thanks for reply. it works with Raphael 1.5.2 min version . same we tried with latest available 2.1.0 it is not working.

Comment: Seems like a jsfiddle bug as the browser error log reports Raphael as undefined.

Comment: The link works for me, noticed I can't select Raphael 2? This jsbin works fine: http://jsbin.com/wayasa/2/edit